# Uniform convergence of a sequence of holomorphic polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

This is a two-part question :

1. Let $E = \{|z|=1 \text{ and } \Im{z} \geq 0\}$. Does there exist a sequence of (holomorphic) polynomials in $z$ which converge uniformly on $E$ to $f(z) = \bar{z}$? Justify.
2. Answer the same question for the set $E=\{|z|=1\}$.

**My thoughts**:
From [Mergelyan's Theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem&ei=c567UrinL4X12QWGuID4Aw&usg=AFQjCNFFvbN60jjcboFfa8kodnPeKtyV3Q&sig2=471gxVcbMFrI7E-5uQrPFA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.b2I) we know that any function holomorphic in the interior of a compact set and continuous to the boundary, can be approximated uniformly by polynomials in the compact set. Here $E$ is a compact set, but $f(z)$ is not holomorphic. So it appears that we need some form of the converse of the theorem to prove that such a sequence cannot exist. Also I do not understand if the two parts will lead to different answers and how so.

Comment: Since $\bar z = \frac1z$ on $E$, you can get away with the slightly easier Runge's theorem for 1., instead of applying Mergelyan's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mergelyan's theorem applies to sets even without interior!  In this case it only requires that the function be continuous.  It is truly a powerful result.

As for the second case, what does the Cauchy integral formula tell you about a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to some function on the unit cicle?

Comment: Ok. I see. So for the first case $f(z) = \bar{z} = 1/z$ is continuous on $E$ and hence we can apply Mergelyan's theorem to confirm existence of such a sequence. 
For the second case, since $\mathbb{C}\setminus E$ is not connected, hence Mergelyan does not apply. By Cauchy integral formula and Cauchy's theorem we get a contradiction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: when $|z|=1$, $\overline{z} = 1/z$.

Mergelyan's theorem (if you want to use polynomials) requires ${\mathbb C} \backslash E$ to be connected.